Combine different mixamo animations (first let the character their hand, then turn left and continue walking)
I am a beginner at Blender. I am trying to combine different mixamo animations together in Blender. First, I want my character to wave their hand at the camera then start walking and turn right, after turning right, the character continue to walk and then sit down (a series of action will happen after they sit down). This was what I did so far that it did not work.

First, I combined the series of actions that will happen after they turn right into one skin (by copy and paste the animation keyframes on the timeline).

Then, I created an "Empty" and put the character/skin that has the series of animations under this "Empty" (i.e. make the Empty the parent of the character).

then I rotated the "Empty" on the Z axis 90 degrees so its facing the same orientation with another skin I downloaded from mixamo (which is the one that walk and turn right - its called "Right Turn W_Briefcase" on mixamo).


4.Then I selected the armature of the combined action series (in step 1) and pressed Command+A => Apply "Location" to make sure the rotation I did with the Empty will be applied to the character/skin as well.

I selected the armature that is in the Empty (the one that I rotated) and opened "Nonlinear Animation".

I don't know what to do next. I don't know how to combine the skin that contains a series of action with the skin that turned right so that as soon as the skin finishes turning right, the skin will continue walking and sit down and complete a series of action in that same direction without return to its original position.
I hope what I described will make sense. Thank you so much in advance.

There are lots of YT videos online about combining Mixamo animations in Blender. A quick search shows this, this and this although some may not be for the very latest Blender versions. CGDive has done a series of tutorials here.

There is a great video which covers this topic comprehensively : Here: link on youtube
